# My onclick event performs when the page loads instead of when the button is clicked, and i don't know why

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
    function ajax_post() {

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var working='working';
    xmlhttp.open("POST","process_form.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            // success
            var return_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }

xmlhttp.send(working);
alert("The ajax function is running!");
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Processing. Please wait...";

}

var costButton = document.getElementById('cost-value');

costButton.onclick = ajax_post();
```

I'm trying to learn how to take a variable from javascript and send it to a separate php file for processing (i'm gonna put this in a database). My first problem seems to be that rather than the function running when i click on my cost-value button, it runs when the page loads, and the second problem appears to be that the variable i try to send (working) doesn't actually get sent. This is very new to me. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the `onclick` to the return value of the function, since you're executing the function with the parenthesis. Remove the `()` from the `onclick` and it will work as expected.

```
costButton.onclick = ajax_post;
```

In order for this to work you need to make sure either:

This script appears just before the closing body tag `</body>`
or you wrap it in a callback for when the document is ready for JS.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   // Your code here
 })
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this didn't work for me. The function no longer runs as soon as the page loads, but neither will it run when i click on my button. Any other thoughts?

Comment: put your script at the bottom, right before the `</body>` tag, it has to load after the element with the ID gets created

Comment: Silly me, i double-checked my page and saw my own error in my code, so now it works as expected... Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated my answer with some other information about location and waiting for DOM content to be ready.